# lightly modified yo generator results in ENOENT No bower.json present

Tags: gulp, yeoman, enoent

I have a lightly modified version of generator-webapp [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/generator-ninthlink). There are small updates to the README and I added support for UnCSS (along with the ability to toggle this selection on the welcome screen).

Running the generator on a Mac works perfectly. However, on my Windows 10 (64-bit) machine I see the error:

`npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory...No description, No repository field, No README data, No license field... ENOENT No bower.json present`

The command prompt (Babun, CMD, or PowerShell) will then freeze. Inspecting the directory will show only a dummyfile.txt and an empty node_modules folder. I've tried uninstalling and re-installing node, but this has not helped.

node v5.10.1 |
npm v3.8.3 |
bower v1.7.9 |
yo v1.7.0 |
gulp CLI v1.2.1

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been resolved. It's hard to pin down the cause with any certainty, but I eventually made a few trivial updates to the README and updated the version number in the package.json file.

I then re-published the module to npmjs.com and used Yeoman's update generator feature to install the latest version of my custom generator. After doing all this, it works like a charm.